# Ternary Operator in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

Why this code do not want to work ?

```
<?php
$currMonth='01';
?>

<a class="btn btn-xs btn-<?php ($currMonth=='01') ? 'primary' : 'default'; ?>-outline">
```

My output is empty:

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn--outline">
```

Thanks.

Comment: hey @Francois welcome to stackoverflow, please accept the answer if your question was answered.

Comment: Hi @Francois.. hope my answer will help you

Comment: @JasonNathan: There's a [time limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/) of 15 minutes. :)

Comment: Haha, thanks @AmalMurali. Didn't look at the time this question was posted. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working. It is just not outputting something because you haven't told php to do so. Change `<?php` to e.g. `<?php echo`.

Comment: Grr... So easy. Thanks a lot pduersteler.

Answer (score 2):

please use following code...

"echo " is missing

```
<?php
$currMonth='01';
?>

<a class="btn btn-xs btn-<?php echo ($currMonth=='01') ? 'primary' : 'default'; ?>-outline">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<?=` this operator

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-<?= ($currMonth=='01') ? 'primary' : 'default'; ?>-outline">
```

or use echo as other suggested

You can read more about it on site below

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php
```

> echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.

Comment: This requires the `short_open_tag` configuration to be enabled on PHP versions before 5.4. Here's more: [Is it bad practice to use <?= tag in PHP](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/151661/98783) . +1 anyway.

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes you're right I've edited post and gave a link.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function to print out the string!

```
<?php echo ($currMonth=='01') ? 'primary' : 'default'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and your code will work:

```
<?php
$currMonth='01';
?>

<a class="btn btn-xs btn-<?php echo ($currMonth=='01') ? 'primary' : 'default'; ?>-outline">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution

```
<?php
$currMonth='01';
?>

<a class="btn btn-xs btn-<?php echo ($currMonth==='01') ? 'primary' : 'default'; ?>-outline">Test</a>
```